# Two Factor Issuer

Tags: django-two-factor-auth

I have the django-two-factor-auth package working on my development server, I noticed however that the google authenticator app shows the ip:port after scanning the QR code. Is there a way to set the issuer to something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that django-two-factor-auth uses the function `django.contrib.sites.shortcuts.get_current_site` to determine the issuer.

In order to change the value of the issuer you need to change the `name` field of the existing `Site` object with your desired value, this can be done through the django admin site.